# Android_Passing parameter URL

Tags: javascript, php, android, url

I would like to send a variable on a website from my Android application so I tried this:

```js
    OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

    URLConnection connexion = null;

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String data = msg.getData().getString("receivedData");

            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(t-lastTime > 100) {     // Pour eviter que les messages soit coupes
                ReceptionDetect.append("\n");
                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            ReceptionDetect.append(data);

            try {

                // Encodage des paramètres de la requête
                String donnees = URLEncoder.encode("Variable="+data);

                // On a envoyé les données à une adresse distante
                URL url = new URL("http://MyWebsite/myPhp.php");
                connexion = url.openConnection();
                connexion.setDoOutput(true);
                //connexion.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

                // On envoie la requête ici
                writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connexion.getOutputStream());
                // On insère les données dans notre flux
                writer.write(donnees);
                // Et on s'assure que le flux est vidé
                writer.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                try{writer.close();}catch(Exception e){}


        }
    }
    };
```

With this php on my web site : `$_GET['Variable'];
echo 'Le détecteur a répondu : ';
echo ($Variable);`

Or also with a txt file open in the php :

```html
<?php

$_GET['Variable'];


 // Open the text file
 $f = fopen("TextRecevoir.txt", "w");
// Write text
 fwrite($f, $_GET["Variable"]);
// Close the text file
 fclose($f);
// Open file for reading, and read the line
 $f = fopen("TextRecevoir.txt", "r");
 

?>
```

But it doesn't work, the application starts but nothing is not written in the php file.
If someone can help me I don't understand why it does not work.
Thank you

-> Yes I put the internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: why don't you use volley?

Comment: Well I already watched the tuto on developer (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)  and I am currently trying but not with suceed but I also would like to know why my code doesn't work.

Comment: honestly speaking, copy paste of volley code is much faster than debugging your code. And when it comes to your code, where are you appending the params to your url?

Comment: Finally my code was right the bug was in the php file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example how i done it.
Maybe there are compilation errors cause i shorted it, so you can read it better.
Its a class extension of Async Task.

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Check extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String urlString="http://myserver.com/add.php"; // URL to call
        String resultToDisplay = "";

        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            URL url= new URL(urlString+"?hello="+params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(3000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("marketdebug",e.getMessage());
            error=true;
            error_resp=e.getMessage();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        try {
            resultToDisplay = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultToDisplay;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "RESULT:"+result);
    }

}
```

Execution:

```
    Check saveData = new Check();

    String myVariable="TEST";
    saveData.execute(myVariable);
```

Comment: Well in fact the mistake was in my php so your code works !!